# Paraller.ForEach does not work for me

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I have `Parallel.ForEach` around some code, but it gives me different result than non-paraller code. So for diagnostic purposes I did wrap entire code using `lock` keyword:

```
var someArray = new double[123];
var syncObject = new Object();

Parallel.ForEach (windows, (win) =>
{
    lock (syncObject) // now it should execute sequentially?
    {
          // do something with someArray
    }
});
```

I thought lock will make it non-parallel, but I still get issues.
I thought it will be acting same as:

```
windows.ToList().ForEach ( (win) =>
{
    // do something with someArray
});
```

How it is possible that lock does not kills parallelism in this case?

Comment: It will force the code to be serialized.  Apparently your problem isn't with the parallelization with the code, but with something else.  Without knowing what you're doing, or having a reproducing example, we couldn't possibly say what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Serialized? Can you tell more? I'm going home right now, next day I will add more details, if it is possible, because I have alot of code.

Comment: No, we can't tell you more, you have code that isn't working even when it's not parallelized.  There are all sorts of things that could be wrong with it, but iterations running at the same time isn't one of them.

Comment: It means that only one loop will run at a time, but the order might be different.  Most likely your code depends on the order.

Comment: @juharr: you have right, problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is incorrect with regards to serial execution of the code for the snippet you've pasted.

```
Parallel.ForEach (windows, (win) =>
{
    lock (syncObject) // now it should execute sequentially?
    {
          // do something with someArray
    }
});
```

The `lock` that you've put there makes sure that only one thread at a time has access to this particular critical section of your code (the code enclosed inside your `lock(syncObject) {}` but does not mean the statement themselves will execute sequentially.

Replace your Parallel.ForEach with a ThreadPool and probably it will make it simpler to understand:

```
foreach(var item in list)
{
      ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(i =>
                                       {
                                           lock (syncObject)
                                           {
                                               // do something with i here
                                           }
                                       }, item);
 }
```

These two snippets are more or less equivalent. As you can see, you first initiate a thread for each item in the list and then inside the thread, you obtain the lock which will make sure no other thread has access to that enclosed critical section. What this does not guarantee however is that they're done in sequence and that the order is preserved.

The order of execution of threads in a thread pool are out of your control and as such, it's not possible to guarantee any ordering using thread pools (at least, not in a conventional sense).

Now let's have a look at this example that will make things hopefully clearer:

```
var syncObject = new Object();
var list = new List<int>();
for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
{
    list.Add(i);
}

Parallel.ForEach(list, item =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(item + " waiting to be executed on " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    lock (syncObject) // now it should execute sequentially?
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item + " executing on " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                Thread.Sleep(100);

     }
 });
```

The result of this execution will be similar to this:

```
0 waiting to be executed on 1
0 executing on 1
2 waiting to be executed on 4
4 waiting to be executed on 6
10 waiting to be executed on 9
12 waiting to be executed on 5
8 waiting to be executed on 10
16 waiting to be executed on 7
6 waiting to be executed on 8
14 waiting to be executed on 3
1 waiting to be executed on 11
2 executing on 4
10 executing on 9
3 waiting to be executed on 4
11 waiting to be executed on 9
16 executing on 7
14 executing on 3
17 waiting to be executed on 7
15 waiting to be executed on 3
8 executing on 10
9 waiting to be executed on 10
4 executing on 6
12 executing on 5
5 waiting to be executed on 6
6 executing on 8
13 waiting to be executed on 5
1 executing on 1
7 waiting to be executed on 8
3 executing on 4
18 waiting to be executed on 1
11 executing on 9
17 executing on 7
15 executing on 3
9 executing on 10
5 executing on 6
13 executing on 5
7 executing on 8
18 executing on 1
19 waiting to be executed on 1
19 executing on 1
```

As you can see, there may be multiple threads waiting to enter the critical section but there will only ever be one thread that will execute the statement inside the `lock` at any given time. **However** the order of the execution is random and not sequential because of the nature of the ThreadPool thread management and scheduling.

Comment: After 5 minutes on fresh air, I solved my problem. It's exactly what you say. Tasks are executind in more or less random order. And I was computing floating point numbers. So usually using floating point: A+B+C != A+C+B (if C != B). This problem gave me very small differences in my computations. Thanks for detailed post.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code to PLINQ which is equivalent to your `Parallel.ForEach`:

```
        windows
            .AsParallel()
            .ForAll((win) =>
        {
            //DoSomething
        });
```

Then add `WithDegreeOfParallelism(1)` to **"KILL"** the parallelism. So you can see whetehr your bugs come form parallely running threads or from something else.

```
        windows
            .AsParallel()
            .WithDegreeOfParallelism(1)
            .ForAll((win) =>
        {
            //DoSomething
        });
```